# Dividing Divergent and Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fractions

Let $a_n$ be a diverging sequence and $b_n$ be a converging sequence. With that in mind does $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ always diverge?

If so, what is the proof for this?

Comment: One of the intermediate results in Real Analysis is that if $\langle r_n\rangle$ and $\langle s_n\rangle$ are two convergent sequences, then the sequence $$\langle {r_n} \times {s_n}\rangle$$ is also a convergent sequence.  You can regard $a_n = b_n \times \frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_n$ converge to $l_1$, and suppose $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $l_2$. Then by the [Algebraic Limit Theorem](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Enpgallup/m17_mat25/lecture_notes/lecture_10/m17_mat25_lecture_10_notes.pdf) we have$$\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n\cdot \frac{a_n}{b_n} = l_1l_2.$$ But $$b_n \cdot \frac{a_n}{b_n} =a_n,$$ which is divergent, thus giving us a contradiction. Therefore $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is divergent.

Comment: Thank you, following on from this if the opposite were to happen $a_n$ is convergent and $b_n$ is divergent will $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ always either be divergent or converge to zero?

Comment: @MrMath yep, I think that's right.